# Почему не могу подключить файлы .js?

Tags: javascript

[
Почему не могу подключить файлы .js?

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
> at slick.min.js:1
> at slick.min.js:1

][1](https://i.s)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]tack.imgur.com/T4SjJ.png

Comment: Где находятся вашы файлы?

Comment: Напишите мне полный путь к ним

Comment: Ибо мне кажеться что здесь именно с ними ошибка

Comment: Для этого я и поставила фото. На нем видно где находятся файлы

Comment: На нем видно где они не находятся

Comment: у вас slick.min.js пытается достучаться до jQuery и не находит его. Ищите где файл с 184 строки

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, Вы открываете Ваш html файл в браузере как локальный файл с диска.

```js
console.log(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: 'https:' потерялся в начале